# JMESPath export keys based on value from JSON object

Tags: json, jmespath

I'm trying to filter simple JSON data and export keys with similar values using the JMESPath query. This is my JSON.

```json
{
  "af": "0",
  "al": "2",
  "dz": "0",
  "ad": "2",
  "ao": "1",
  "ag": "2",
  "ar": "2",
  "am": "2",
  "au": "3",
  "at": "2"
}
```

Desired output would be this if I specify `"0"`

```json
{
  "af",
  "dz"
}
```

My current query is `keys(@)[?contains(@, '0')]` but it returns empty array.

Comment: As you might have seen testing `keys(@)`, this destroys the values, so you cannot filter by value on the resulting JSON anymore. A way to filter on an object is to do `*|[?contains(@, '0')]`, but unfortunately, this have the opposite effect, which is to destroy the keys. So, what you are looking for is not feasible in the current version of JMESPath.